# Is there any situation that requires the use of specifically one of or both the words "less" or "more"?

Tags: comparisons

If quantity(s) A is less than quantity(s) B, then by definition quantity(s) B is more than quantity(s) A. It seems to me that you can use only the word "less" or only the word "more" to describe any situation. Is there any situation where specifically one of or both the words must be used to adequately describe a comparison? Or is it technically redundant to have both?

Comment: That's more or less correct.

Comment: Suppose we have a standard value given.  Then we may ask whether this particular sample is more or less than that standard.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to ask "Is the given standard value (more/less) or not (more/less) and not equal to this particular sample?" instead and convey the exact same meaning? Of course it's more clunky but it still conveys the same meaning right? @GEdgar

Comment: B is more than A? Is that even grammatical?

Comment: @TurboAverage419 No one would express a comparison to a standard value by wording it like that. It is redundant. I think GEdgar answered the question although there might be other examples (none of which I can think of).

Comment: @Xanne It is if A and B are numbers. For instance "twenty is more than fifteen" or, perhaps more meaningfully, "three quarters is more than two thirds".